# Remove Google Maps iframe address popup

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I'm in Wordpress and have inserted this iframe into a text widget. However, I can't get the address popup to go away.

I have tried both `iwloc=near` and `iwlock=NoSuchMarker` (end a href on fifth line)

```
<iframe width="295" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=3904+Washington+Parkway,+Idaho+Falls,+Idaho&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=3904+washington+parkway+idah&amp;sll=41.833733,-87.731964&amp;sspn=0.929078,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3904+Washington+Pkwy,+Idaho+Falls,+Bonneville,+Idaho+83404&amp;t=p&amp;ll=43.466874,-111.993513&amp;spn=0.015573,0.025406&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
<br />
<small>
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=3904+Washington+Parkway,+Idaho+Falls,+Idaho&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=3904+washington+parkway+idah&amp;sll=41.833733,-87.731964&amp;sspn=0.929078,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3904+Washington+Pkwy,+Idaho+Falls,+Bonneville,+Idaho+83404&amp;t=p&amp;ll=43.466874,-111.993513&amp;spn=0.015573,0.025406&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=near">
</a>
</small>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works for me.  I updated iwloc=A to iwloc=near.  You were adding that code in the  tag **after** the iframe, not within the iframe src itself.

```
<iframe width="295" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=3904+Washington+Parkway,+Idaho+Falls,+Idaho&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=3904+washington+parkway+idah&amp;sll=41.833733,-87.731964&amp;sspn=0.929078,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3904+Washington+Pkwy,+Idaho+Falls,+Bonneville,+Idaho+83404&amp;t=p&amp;ll=43.466874,-111.993513&amp;spn=0.015573,0.025406&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=near&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
<br />
<small>
<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=3904+Washington+Parkway,+Idaho+Falls,+Idaho&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=3904+washington+parkway+idah&amp;sll=41.833733,-87.731964&amp;sspn=0.929078,2.113495&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=3904+Washington+Pkwy,+Idaho+Falls,+Bonneville,+Idaho+83404&amp;t=p&amp;ll=43.466874,-111.993513&amp;spn=0.015573,0.025406&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=near">
</a>
</small>
```

Comment: Beautiful. You're a life saver!