# How to remove address box from google maps?

Tags: google-maps, maps

I want to remove address box from embedded google maps 
Here's my website http://demo82.com/testing/?page_id=598

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512854/remove-google-maps-iframe-address-popup

Comment: but in my google map code iwloc=A not given

Answer (score 0):

[Remove address bubble from Google Maps iframe](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/remove-address-bubble-from-google-maps-iframe/)  manually turn the address bubble off Google map